# emails as email.Message class objects in Python

Tags: python, email, parsing, pop3

How do I use poplib, and download mails as message instances from email.Message class from email module in Python?

I am writing a program, which analyzes, all emails for specific information, storing parts of the message into a database. I can download the entire mail as text, howver walking through text searching for attachments is difficult.

idea is to parse messages for information

Comment: Do you also need to parse through the attachments (at least the text-type ones) as well, looking for 'specific information'?

Comment: Yes! That's a goal. But immdly I need a way to scan main content!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use the `FeedParser` class in the `email.feedparser` module to construct an `email.Message` object from the messages read from the server with `poplib`.

specifically:

```
import poplib
import email

pop = poplib.POP3( "server..." )
[establish connection, authenticate, ...]
raw = pop.retr( 1 )
pop.close()

parser = email.parser.FeedParser()
for line in raw[1]:
    parser.feed( str( line+b'\n', 'us-ascii' ) )
message = parser.close()
```

Comment: You can use BytesFeedParser to save you the trouble of converting to str (it also uses surrogateescape mode so as not to break on invalid characters)

Answer (score 2):

Doesn't deal with character set issues like Adrien Plisson's answer.

```
import poplib
import email

pop = poplib.POP3( "server..." )
[establish connection, authenticate, ...]
raw = pop.retr( 1 )
pop.close()

message = email.message_from_string('\n'.join(raw[1]))
```